How can I search File Explorer for files only (i.e. exclude folders) in Windows 11?
How can I specify that a search using File Explorer should return files only? It seems like they have deprecated kind: operator
I just wanted to leave a comment to same question regarding Win-10, but I don't have enough reputation, even to answer there. So I'm going to answer here instead.

This question is similar to: How can I search File Explorer for files only (i.e. exclude folders) in Windows 10?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. It's still the same as in WIn 10

@drmoishe-pippik
If you read my question thouroughly, you may notice, that it's not exactly the same, at least in my occasion: the kind operator doesn't work anymore for me.
And I would like to add this notice as a comment to question you mentioned (so did I in my question), but due to lack of reputation the only way to post this information I found was to post a new question.

This is not a duplicate. The marked dupe is specific to Win10 and OP clearly notes the solution there did not work, which satisfies the requirements to note the critical differences. Igor, thanks for posting this and answering it. The reason you got flagged is that it is far more common for people to say what you said "I wanted to leave a comment" and mean a comment. You actually have a different question and a good answer for it. Perhaps editing your post to say you know there is an apparet duplicate, but it is limited to Win10 and the solution to it does not apply to Win11, will help

So I asked and answered myself.
Just typing NOT folder did the work.
Also it seems that multiple search clauses are automatically wrapped with AND operators, but I'm not sure.
E.g.:
NOT .pptx NOT folder

